# Gimp 2 Cogs and Gears shape

Tags: gimp, shapes, plugin

I'm new to using gimp 2 and so far I've been having fun using it~

I just want to ask if there's a way to add customized shapes in gimp 2.
Specifically the cogs and gears shapes.

I've tried google but my searching skills are waaayyy too poor or I

thanks in advance~

Comment: There are several scripts around that add things around a circle, but it depends on how realistic you want the gears to look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like:

https://woodgears.ca/gear_cutting/template.html

To generate your gears. Not really worth time investing more in this kind of stuff unless your engineering a solution in which case your not using gimp anyway.

[image]

**Image 1**: Gear template generated with the woodgears webpage